# Looking for resnet implementation in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, resnet

Are there any resnet implementations in tensorflow? I came across a few (e.g. https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-resnet, https://github.com/xuyuwei/resnet-tf) but these implementations have some bugs (e.g. see the Issues section on the respective github page). I am looking to train imagenet using resnet and looking for tensorflow implementations.

Comment: Here is an implementation I created using TensorFlow GPU in Docker using the full ImageNet dataset trained on 2x NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti’s. https://blog.exxactcorp.com/deep-learning-with-tensorflow-training-resnet-50-from-scratch-using-the-imagenet-dataset/ It’s based mostly off the official TensorFlow implementation, with some tips and tricks I found along the way. It also goes over launching and interfacing with the TF docker environment. Let me know if you have any issues or questions! James

Comment: I wanted to find out if there is the best way to download the ImageNet dataset. I could not find a straight forward workaround for this.

Answer (score 6):

There are some (50/101/152) in [tensorflow:models/slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#Pretrained).

The [example notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb) shows how to get a pre-trained `inception` running, `res-net` is probably no different.

Comment: Hi~ I found that there are models of resnet-v1 and v2 in the link you proposed. And I noticed that there are pre-trained weights for resnet-v1 but no pre-trained weights for resnet-v2. Do you know if the pre-trained weights of v2 are available now?

Answer (score 3):

I implemented a cifar10 version of ResNet with tensorflow. The validation errors of ResNet-32, ResNet-56 and ResNet-110 are 6.7%, 6.5% and 6.2% respectively. (You can modify the number of layers easily as hyper-parameters.)

I tried to be friendly with new ResNet fan and wrote everything straightforward. You can run the cifar10_train.py file directly without any downloads.

https://github.com/wenxinxu/resnet_in_tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below for custom implementation of Resnet34. You can use this model and build you image classification model.

```
#Dependencies

import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Layer, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Conv2D, Add, BatchNormalization


CONFIGURATIONS = {
               
                "NUM_CLASSES" : 3

             }

 # Custom Class Definition inherited from Model class

 class Resnet34(Model):

   def __init__(self,):
    super(Resnet34, self).__init__(name="resnet_34")

    self.conv_1 = CustomConv2D(64, 7, 2, padding="same")
    self.max_pool = MaxPooling2D(3, 2)

    self.conv_2_1 = ResidualBlock(64)
    self.conv_2_2 = ResidualBlock(64)
    self.conv_2_3 = ResidualBlock(64)

    self.conv_3_1 = ResidualBlock(128, 2) #2 for downsampling
    self.conv_3_2 = ResidualBlock(128)
    self.conv_3_3 = ResidualBlock(128)
    self.conv_3_4 = ResidualBlock(128)

    self.conv_4_1 = ResidualBlock(256, 2)  # 2 for downsampling
    self.conv_4_2 = ResidualBlock(256)
    self.conv_4_3 = ResidualBlock(256)
    self.conv_4_4 = ResidualBlock(256)
    self.conv_4_5 = ResidualBlock(256)
    self.conv_4_6 = ResidualBlock(256)

    self.conv_5_1 = ResidualBlock(512, 2)  # 2 for downsampling
    self.conv_5_2 = ResidualBlock(512)
    self.conv_5_3 = ResidualBlock(512)

    self.global_pool = GlobalAveragePooling2D()

    self.fc_3 = Dense(CONFIGURATIONS["NUM_CLASSES"], activation="softmax")


   def call(self, x, training=True):

    x = self.conv_1(x)
    x = self.max_pool(x)

    x = self.conv_2_1(x, training)
    x = self.conv_2_2(x, training)
    x = self.conv_2_3(x, training)

    x = self.conv_3_1(x, training)
    x = self.conv_3_2(x, training)
    x = self.conv_3_3(x, training)
    x = self.conv_3_4(x, training)

    x = self.conv_4_1(x, training)
    x = self.conv_4_2(x, training)
    x = self.conv_4_3(x, training)
    x = self.conv_4_4(x, training)
    x = self.conv_4_5(x, training)
    x = self.conv_4_6(x, training)

    x = self.conv_5_1(x, training)
    x = self.conv_5_2(x, training)
    x = self.conv_5_3(x, training)

    x = self.global_pool(x)

    return self.fc_3(x)


 # Custom Conv2D Class inherited from layer
class CustomConv2D(Layer):

   def __init__(self, n_filters, kernel_size, n_strides, padding="valid"):
    super(CustomConv2D, self).__init__(name="custom_conv2D")

    self.conv = Conv2D(
        filters=n_filters,
        kernel_size=kernel_size,
        activation="relu",
        strides= n_strides,
        padding=padding
    )

   self.batch_norm = BatchNormalization()

   def call(self, x, training=True):

    x = self.conv(x)
    x = self.batch_norm(x, training)

    return x


#Custom Residual Block inherited from Layer class
class ResidualBlock(Layer):

   def __init__(self, n_channels, n_strides=1):
    super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__(name="res_block")

    self.dotted = (n_strides!=1)

    self.custom_conv_1 = CustomConv2D(n_channels, 3, n_strides, padding="same")
    self.custom_conv_2 = CustomConv2D(n_channels, 3, 1, padding="same")

    self.activation = Activation('relu')

    if self.dotted:
        self.custom_conv_3 = CustomConv2D(n_channels, 1, n_strides) # 1  X 1 Conv layer


  def call(self, input, training):

    x = self.custom_conv_1(input, training)
    x = self.custom_conv_2(x)

    if self.dotted:
        x_add = self.custom_conv_3(input, training)
        x_add = Add()([x, x_add])
    else:
        x_add = Add()([x, input])


    return self.activation(x_add)


 #Calling with default build
 resnet_34 = Resnet34()
 resnet_34(tf.zeros([1, 256,256, 3]), training=False)
 resnet_34.summary()
```

Answer (score -2):

I implemented Resnet by use of ronnie.ai and keras. Both of tool are great.
While ronnie is more easy from scratch.